# How to prevent custom elements from overlapping

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to understand anchors and use them in custom elements.

This is a simple rectangle, but my problem is that both custom rectangle elements overlap each other.

```qml
//CRect.qml

import QtQuick 2.12

Item {
    property var bgColor: "red"

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: bgColor
    }

    // main.qml

    Rectangle {
        id: containerId
        width: 300
        height: width
        border.color: "black"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        CRect {
            id: topLeftRectId
        }

        CRect {
            id: topCenterRectId
            bgColor: "blue"
            anchors.left: topLeftRectId.right
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the Item in your `CRect` a size. Otherwise the anchors work on Items with width and height of 0 and the alignment seams to be wrong because the internal rectangles overlap their parent.

Try this:

```
Item {
    property color bgColor: "red"

    // size the parent
    width:100
    height:100

    Rectangle {
        // give your rectangle the parent size
        anchors.fill: parent
        color:bgColor
    }

}
```

You can watch the effect, if you set the clipping for your second CRect to true or false:

```
clip: true
```

If it is set to `true` the rectangle is clipped to the size of its parent (which is 0) and it disappears.

Comment: nice to learn something new. thanks for the answer.!

Comment: @AmanKashyap if that answered your question, please do accept it by checking it to thank the answerer, and upvote it in the future once you have enough reputation points.